# Covariance matrix of uniform distribution in $L^p$ Euclidean ball

Tags: probability, covariance

Let $$X=\operatorname{Unif}\left(\left\{x:\ \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\le 1\right\}\right)$$

Is there some method to calculate the covariance matrix of $X$?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you define the uniform distribution on such a set? It is usually only defined on sets of finite measure. Here, I don't even see a measure.

Comment: I forget to add $|\cdot|$. For example, when $p=2$, the set is a ball. For $p\rightarrow\infty$, the set is a hypecube.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you work this out for a very simple case (e.g. the $L_{\infty}$ hypercube for $n=2$)?

Comment: For $L_\infty$ it is easy because $X_i$ are independent. But when $X_i$ are dependent I have no idea to deal with such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\xi_i,\ldots,\xi_n$ are i.i.d. random variables with density $f(x)=(2\Gamma(1+1/p))^{-1}e^{-|x|^p}$ and $\zeta\sim \text{exp(1)}$ independent of $\xi\equiv (\xi_i,\ldots,\xi_n)^{\top}$, then
$$
X=\frac{\xi}{(\sum_{i=1}^n |\xi_i|^p+\zeta)^{1/p}}
$$
is uniformly distributed in the unit $L_p$-ball ([ref](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aop/1109868589)). Since $x\mapsto xf(x)/(|x|^p+w)^{1/p}$, $w\ge 0$, is an odd function, $\mathsf{E}X_i=0$. Similarly, $\mathsf{E}X_iX_j=0$ for $i\ne j$. Finally, the second moment of $X_i$ is
$$
\mathsf{E}X_i^2=\int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{x_i^2}{(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p+z)^{2/p}}\prod_{k=1}^n f(x_k)\times e^{-z}\,dx\,dz,
$$
which can be computed at least numerically.